# How do I write a breeze Predicate equivalent to the following SQL

Tags: sql, breeze

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    Table
WHERE 
  FirstName = 'Wilson' 
  AND (START_DATE = '1/1/2014' OR START_DATE > '1/2/2014')
```

Comment: provide more information on what exactly you want ?

Comment: Question is clear to me.  In fact, this question is close enough to mine that it will be very helpful to me.  I think that if you don't know breeze then it's not clear at all.  But, then you shouldn't worry about understanding a question about a topic with which you are not familiar.  ...Note that both freelancer and ward got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have controller and it has:

```
     [HttpGet]
     public IQueryable<Tables> GetTables()
     {
         return _contextProvider.Context.Set<Tables>();
     }
```

Create Predicate:

```
var p1 = new breeze.Predicate.create("FirstName ", "==", "Wilson");
var p2 = new breeze.Predicate.create("START_DATE ", "==", "1/1/2014");
var p3 = new breeze.Predicate.create("START_DATE ", ">", "1/1/2014");
var orPred = new breeze.Predicate.or(p2, p3);
var andPred = Predicate.and(p1, orPred );
// You should parse "1/1/2014" to DateTime type first
```

The query will be:

```
var query= new breeze.EntityQuery().from("GetTables").where(andPred);
```

Comment: There is a typo in your second predicate missing a quote on the operator.

Answer (score 5):

@freelancer's answer is headed in the right direction ... but a bit verbose for my tastes.

I'm also not convinced that I can count on an automatic conversion of '1/1/2014' into a `DateTime` value when the query is analyzed. When I try a predicate like this:

`var p2 = breeze.Predicate.create('StartDate', '>', '1/2/2014')`

Breeze throws an error in my queries.

> Error: '1/2/2014' is not a valid dateTime

Here's an alternative:

```
var pred = breeze.Predicate
            // weird: any day in 2014 except Jan 2nd ???
            .create('StartDate', '==', new Date('1/1/2014'))
            .or(    'StartDate', '>',  new Date('1/2/2014'))
            .and(   'FirstName', '==', 'Wilson');

var query= breeze.EntityQuery.from("GetTables").where(pred);
```

Notice the **left-to-right composition of the predicates**.

1. The `create` call predicate creates the date-equality predicate
2. The `or` call returns a predicate which is the OR of the first predicate and the second date condition. This is the OR predicate
3. The third `and` call returns the AND of the OR-predicate and the name-test.

Here's a nifty trick to display your predicate as an OData query clause:

```
// Should use the target EntityType but this dummy will do for now
var dummyEntityType = new EntityType(new breeze.MetadataStore());
console.log("OData predicate: " + pred.toODataFragment(dummyEntityType )));
```

It prints

> OData predicate: ((StartDate eq datetime'2014-01-01T08:00:00.000Z') or (StartDate gt datetime'2014-01-02T08:00:00.000Z')) and (FirstName eq 'Wilson')

### Dates are tricky!

You didn't ask but I'll give you my $0.02 on date risk.

First, I'd want to be certain that my dates in the database have no time components ... or this query won't work at all because no 'StartDate in your database will pass the equality test.

Second, using text dates like this runs the risk of internationalization problems. Is the `'1/2/2014'` supposed to be January 2nd or February 1st? I'd eliminate ambiguity by supplying real date values as in this next example.

```
var pred = breeze.Predicate
            .create('StartDate', '==', new Date(2014, 0, 1)) // Jan===0 in JavaScript
            .or(    'StartDate', '>',  new Date(2014, 0, 2))
            .and(   'FirstName', '==', 'Wilson');
```

This predicate (like the one above) produces

> OData predicate: ((StartDate eq datetime'2014-01-01T08:00:00.000Z') or (StartDate gt datetime'2014-01-02T08:00:00.000Z')) and (FirstName eq 'Wilson')

Third, now you have a potential timezone problem. I'd want to be certain that I eliminate TIMEZONE effects by doing everything in UTC on both client and server. **So I'd actually write**:

```
var pred = breeze.Predicate
            .create('StartDate', '==', new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1))) // Jan===0 in JavaScript
            .or(    'StartDate', '>',  new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 0, 2)))
            .and(   'FirstName', '==', 'Wilson');
```

This predicate produces:

> OData predicate: ((StartDate eq datetime'2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z') or (StartDate gt datetime'2014-01-02T00:00:00.000Z')) and (FirstName eq 'Wilson')

Comment: Cannot ... upvote ... enough ...

Comment: Thanks @Ward awesome answer, what I didn't understand was how Breeze deals with odata operator precedence (**and** is always evaluated before **or**). Now I see that Predicate.or and Predicate.and wrap the predicate in parentheses so I can control the order of evaluation.