# nested predicates in breeze.js

Tags: javascript, breeze

Is it possible to use some sort of nested predicates in breeze.js?

I want something like `(a) and(b or c or d))`

I am only able to chain the predicates without the logical brackets with:

```
 predicates = predicates.and(a);
 predicates = predicates.or(b);
 predicates = predicates.or(c);
 predicates = predicates.or(d); 
 // predicates not nested: a and b or c or d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compose your predicates:

```
var leftSide = predicates.or(b).or(c).or(d);
var composedPredicate = leftSide.and(a);
```

It will give you:

```
(b or c or d) and a
```

Edit:

Just found a very useful thread:

[How do I write a breeze Predicate equivalent to the following SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053168/how-do-i-write-a-breeze-predicate-equivalent-to-the-following-sql)